# Why are there three copies of Notepad in Windows 7 64bit?

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, shortcuts, notepad

I am using Windows 7 64bit version.

I found notepad.exe in the following three paths:

```
C:\Windows\notepad.exe  
C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\notepad.exe
```

I know `C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe` contains 64bit app and `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\notepad.exe` contains 32bit app.

> Why is it stored in the C:\Windows\notepad.exe?
>   Which version of app is it either 64 or 32 bit?
>   When I use notepad shortcut through the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, which app is going to be execute?

Note: I am asking this question in specific way using `notepad.exe`, like `notepad.exe` I can see some other files also.

Answer (score 5):

The reasoning behind the redundant files is, in short, Compatibility [[see here]](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/28/563008.aspx)

In the 64-bit version of Windows, both the `%SYSTEMROOT%\notepad.exe` and the `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\notepad.exe` executables are the same file and thus of 64-bit nature.

As for which file <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> references, I believe it's based on whatever directory is listed first in the `%PATH%` variable. This is, by default, `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32`